# HTML5 page with Playframework2.0.2

Tags: playframework-2.0

Trying to include simple `HTML5` page instead of `scala` templates..

For this I have tried creating a simple `HTML` page in my `views`, But how can I redirect my app to this page ?

What I am trying to achieve is to use HTML pages as my UI and Play controller for `POST` and `GET` `JSON` data to the ui pages which will allow me to decouple UI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the `routes` file, on the end there is route for `assets` - static files like CSS, JS and images placed in public directory.

You can create similar folder for your static HTML files and add a separate route(s) the same as for assets.

You can also add your file into the `views` as ie. `static_html5.scala.html` and just don't add any scala functions to it (just to remember leave first line of the file empty) In such case only thing you'll need to remember is to replace any `@` to `@@` (ie.: `My email is bob@@example.com` )

In such case you can render it as a common template without params:

```
public static Result index(){
    return ok(static_html5.render());
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. Why cant I see my html pages in controller ? I need to execute `play run` ofttn for IntelliJ to identify the pages.

Comment: Yes, Play **must** be running **all the time** to compile freshly added/changed views. Additionally you need refresh the browser. You can use also `tilde-dev` mode, in such case Play will compile it asap: `play ~run`

Comment: Thanks for the info provided it is very helpful, I have achieved the same by placing the html page in `views`.  am facing problem if I try to place the static `pages` seperately out of `views`, could you provide your sample `conf` to set the pages outside the `views` also is it must to end the pages with `.scala` ?

Comment: When placed outside the views as a static files it doesn't need to have `scala` in the name. Check docs for working with public assets: https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/Assets